# To find the minimum(least) number of Unique numbers in a given list after 'n' reductions

Tags: python, arrays

Problem Statement: *To find the minimum(least) number of Unique numbers in a given list after 'n' reductions*

Input:

```
N and an Array(or list)

Where 0 < N < len(Array)
```

N is the number of reductions possible  and the input for the array needs to be separated by commas(,)

Example 1:

```
N = 2

Array = 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4
```

Output: 
To find the Least or minimum number of unique elements after deleting N number of elements in the Array

In the above example,
After deleting N = 2 number of elements from the Array

In the above example 1, 2 should be deleted from the array
         3, 3, 4, 4 will be remaining
So, 2 unique elements remaining after deleting 2 elements from the array

So, the output should be 2

Example 2:

```
N = 2 [ number of reductions possible]

Input Array : 1,3,4,1,2,4,2,2 

Output: 3 [least number of unique elements]
```

Explanation :[1,1,2,2,4,4] will be the resultant array when [2,3] are removed

Supposed to be coded in Python exclusively but solutions in any language will be appreciated.

Comment: Can I ask where you got this problem from?

Comment: It was from a recent test I took for a company called Infosys.

Comment: Dynamic programming is not needed for this problem. Are you allowed to use the standard library? Are there any requirements on the efficiency of the code?

Comment: Can you show any of your own work on this problem, preferably with some code attempt?

Comment: Yes, standard libraries are allowed. And I've attempted to solve it but couldn't find an apt algorithm to approach the problem. Hence the lack of any code. I apologize.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finding the minimum number of unique elements is equivalent to finding the maximum number of duplicates.

The driving idea here would be to use your reductions to take out the elements that appear the fewest number of times first. In order to do that, you'd want to count the number of occurrences of each element in the list, sort them by number of occurrences, and remove them from least to most until you run out of deletions. The only tricky part is the first part, and that's only if you have to code it in pure python (@DerekLangley's answer gives a good example of how you might do that).

If you're allowed to import other parts of the standard library, then `collections.Counter` makes quick work of this problem. Here's a sample implementation that doesn't account for anything that could go wrong (such as an empty list, or `N` being larger than `len(lst)` - these are things that the interviewer would expect you to mention and know how to handle, so work on that).

```
import collections
...
def min_uniques(N, lst):
    # use collections.Counter to get a sorted list of unique elements and their frequencies
    most_common = collections.Counter(lst).most_common()
    # returns [(most_frequent, num_occurrences), ...], so we pull from the back to get fewest occurrences.
    # We could reverse the list and pull from the front but that would be less efficient
    while N >= most_common[-1][1]:
        # remove the element with lowest count and subtract its count from N, all at once
        N -= most_common.pop()[1] 
    # return the number of unique elements left, after we can no longer remove enough to decrease that count
    return len(most_common)

min_uniques(2, [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4])
# 2
min_uniques(2, [1, 3, 4, 1, 2, 4, 2, 2])
# 3
```

My comments on that code represent how I would talk through the problem with the interviewer as I was writing it. This is a four-line python function, but I'm pretty sure you could also do it in two - the interviewer might ask for how you can improve this code, and if you can put in that as an example (maybe say "I think it would use mechanism X or mechanism Y, but I'd have to look at the documentation and do some tinkering first).

I don't especially see how Dynamic Programming is relevant here, though I kind of feel like Dynamic Programming is a bit of a buzzword anyway.

Comment: 's a fun programming exercise for me, anyway, and I tried to give advice that'll be applicable to solving this type of problem in a job interview (which is the OP's use case, I assume). This isn't a take-home type of problem - the interview's came and gone, so there's no harm in showing how the question would have been solved, so that you can take similar lessons and use it in the future.

Comment: Thank you, @GreenCloakGuy
Much appreciated for your time! 
And I had no clue that the given problem could be addressed in less than 5 LOC.

Answer (score 2):

Since you do not show any code of your own, I will just give some ideas for an algorithm. If you want more details, please show some of your own code.

The `Counter` object in the `collections` module in Python's standard library can count the number of occurrences of each number in the array. Use `Counter` to do that for your array. The size of the resulting `Counter` object is the number of unique items in the array.

Then use `Counter`'s `most_common` method to sort that information from the most popular number to the least popular. Now look at that result from the least popular end. Use your value of `N` to "remove" the least popular values in the array. You don't need to actually do the removal--just do it conceptually. When you have done that removal (conceptually or actually), the size of the `Counter` object is then your answer.

Of course, there are ways to do this without `Counter` but the code will be more lengthy. Again, show some more effort of your own then I will be glad to give more details.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a (probably) inefficient way of doing it.

```
ls = [1,3,4,1,2,4,2,2]
d = {}
for i in ls:
    if i not in d:
        d[i] = 1
    else:
        d[i] += 1
def min_num(n):
    counter = n
    while counter > 0:
        del d[min(d, key = d.get)]
        counter -= 1
    return len(d.keys())
min_num(2)
```

Comment: I realized this solution is wrong...but it shouldn't be difficult to extrapolate from here